# Can't view Github Repos after cloning them into Colaboratory

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, google-drive-shared-drive

I cloned a Github Repository into Colaboratory although it was cloned but i couldn't view it in that particular folder. I changed into "drive" as my working directory but i don't know which directory is that on drive. I moved into drive folder and viewed it's contents, it was present in the drive folder. Please tell me which is the drive folder on Google Drive. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please specify your requirement clearly

Answer (score 4):

First, mount Google Drive in Colab as follows:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/')
```

Enter the authorization code to provide access to your Drive.

Next, cd into the folder you want:

```
%cd '/content/drive/My Drive/[folder name]'
```

Lastly, git clone the GitHub repository:

```
!git clone https://github.com/example/example_repo.git
```

You should now be able to see the repository and its contents in your Drive. Use `!pwd` or `!ls` to check if you are in the correct directory.

Answer (score 0):

Colab runs on a new machine in the cloud. If you git clone in Colab, it won't appear in Gdrive. You need to mount it as shown here.

[How to Upload Many Files to Google Colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48875783/how-to-upload-many-files-to-google-colab)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change Run type to `GPU` and retry the clone.

I met the same problem when using default Jupyter notebook.