# import various files by using google colab

Tags: import, google-colaboratory

I'm the student that learning tensorflow. By the way, when i practice someone's capsule networks project [Click here](https://github.com/www0wwwjs1/Matrix-Capsules-EM-Tensorflow).

I want to run this sample code by using Google Colab, not Ubuntu.

So, I search on google "import python code on Colab", and i find some tips like   [Click here](http://www.pingshiuanchua.com/blog/post/importing-your-own-python-module-or-python-file-in-colaboratory). Other tips are as similar as this code.

But, I want to import many files by one time, not one file by one time.
what can i do import many files by one time?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Option :-** **Upload Data on Google drive and Mount Drive**

See following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48875783/how-to-upload-many-files-to-google-colab) for how to mount Drive

**Second Option :-** **Directly clone git repository**

```
!git clone repo-link
```

You can create your own git fork and work on same.

Comment: Thanks for answering. when I follow 'First option', I success to mount Google drive. But I still fail to open python files on colab. what should I do? Link shows only xlsx files, so i don't know how to open python files in colab.

Comment: Follow the second option.